# Save iptables firewall rules on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables, amazon-linux-2

I'm running Amazon Linux 2, on EC2 instances in AWS. I want to be able to add my own iptables rules, and have them survive reboots.

What is the correct way (or *a* correct way) to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A simple way to do this (which works at the time of writing, with an AMI image timestamped at 2020-05-20) is to enable the `iptables` service. This allows rules to be saved to the system configuration, and be applied every time the instance boots.

First, install the service and activate it:

```sh
yum install iptables-services -y
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables
```

Second, add whatever iptables rules you like.

For example:

```sh
# Enable NAT forwarding
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then, whenever you change the iptables rules:

```sh
service iptables save
```

The currently-applied set of rules are saved to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, and are restored on every boot.

Comment: If one forgets to install `iptables-services`, the last command gives a rather confusing `The service command supports only basic LSB actions... please try to use systemctl."